# Obtaining the element number related to a node of a fastener in Abaqus

Tags: fortran, key, analysis, subroutine, abaqus

I am trying to change the stiffness of a fastener depending on a pressure on it. I am approaching this problem by using field variables and extracting the forces in a fastener from *.fil* file.

The problem is that I need to relate the node number provided by **UFIELD** to element number of the fastener in *.fil* file. I know that the *.fil* file contains that information in record **no. 1900** but when I set *if statement* for that record, it is never hit in my subroutine. Although, when I convert my *.fil* file to ASCII I can see that information there.

The records **No. 1** and **No. 495** are hit properly and I can obtain the element number and internal forces in it.

Moreover, I have tried using **GETPARTINFO** both on the node I have and on the element. But it returns number not related to the node of my fastener or the element itself.

Additionally, I could not obtain fastener **CTF** from the node itself or the material point as the fasteners do not have material points.

If I assume that the nodes and the fastener are in the same order and just match them, my code works nicely on just few element in a tiny model. But in a large model with lots of fasteners, everything gets mixed up.

Any Ideas how to solve this or maybe some remarks on why I cant access **key 1900** from my subroutine or why **GETPARTINFO** does not return what is to be expected?

Comment: I have no idea what is this about (apart that I know that Abaqus is a FEM package). Consider finding some more specialized place for your question. Why is this tagged Fortran? Do you have any Fortran code? All questions here should be about some code or coding problem.

Comment: The Abaqus subroutines are written in Fortran language. This question is purely about Fortran and Abaqus interaction and access to the results and not about mechanics or physics behind FEM. So I thought, it is the right place to ask it.

Anyhow  I think I figured it out myself. I will post the answer later so other people with similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. The key 1900 in .fil file is printed before the default reading position of command

```
call DBFILE(0,ARRAY,JRCD)
```

In order to obtain the required key the file read position must be reset

```
call DBFILE(2,ARRAY,JRCD)
```

But the problem is that keys 1900, 1901, 1933 etc. are generated for every element in the model regardless of your specified elset. Thus I wrote a little subroutine to generate an array of fasteners with their element number and corresponding node number.

```
      subroutine obtain_relation(REL)
      INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'
      DIMENSION ARRAY(513),JRRAY(NPRECD,513),REL(500,3)
      character*8 CVALUE
      EQUIVALENCE (ARRAY(1),JRRAY(1,1)), (ARRAY(4),CVALUE)                   
      !Rewinding the file 
      CALL DBFILE(2,ARRAY,JRCD)
      i = 1
      DO K1=1,999999
          !Start reading output file
          CALL DBFILE(0,ARRAY,JRCD)
          !If the end of the end of pre-step records go to 120 
          IF (KEY .EQ. 2000) GO TO 120
          !If the end of all records is reached go to position 120
          IF (JRCD .NE. 0) GO TO 120
          !The key of the output table is at second possition (first is length of
          !the array)          
          KEY=JRRAY(1,2)
          ! Record 1900 contains information about element conectivity
          IF (KEY .EQ. 1900) THEN
              IF(trim(CVALUE).eq."CONN3D2") then
                  Rel(i,1) = JRRAY (1,3) ! <- Element number
                  Rel(i,2) = JRRAY (1,5) ! <- First node number
                  i = i + 1
              END IF
          END IF

      ENDDO          
 120  Continue
      Return
      end
```

Call this subroutine only once at the start of the analysis after calling POSFIL inside URDFIL and it will return a double precision 3 dimensional matrix with first column containing fastener element number, second column - first node of corresponding fastener and the last one empty. I used the last column to store the corresponding forces.

Hope this was helpful for somebody.